# Implementation strategy for Kubernetes probes

Tags: kubernetes

I am struggling with defining a sane implementation strategy for Kubernetes probes for my product. Digging into the available guidelines, both official docs and field reports, I am not able to identify a common approach with consensus in the ecosystem; and most probably that's expected.

Here's what I plan to implement as probe definition rules:

**Readiness probe**:
Enable it for services handling incoming network traffic.

Question: Any other use case where I should consider a readiness probe for a service?

**Liveness probe**:
This is the most difficult one for me. What I have in mind as a rule is: Don't define it by default and only enable it manually for services where scenarios as deadlocks are detected and only until these bugs are fixed.
I don't see as a healthy approach to just assume that a service will deadlock and leave the liveness probe handle it. First because it is very hard to identify a service deadlock from the probe and second because it would leave bugs unaddressed.

Question: Any other use case where I should consider a liveness probe?

**Startup probe**:
Enable it only when there is a liveness probe enabled on that service.

Question: Without a liveness probe defined, is there any advantage in defining a startup probe?

Answer (score 0):

> Question: Without a liveness probe defined, is there any advantage in
> defining a startup probe?

i am not seeing any advantage in defining the just startup probe without liveness. startup probe is there to protect the slow-starting PODs.

> Question: Any other use case where I should consider a liveness probe?

If the service depends on DB or any other service and inside the backend service code you have a function or endpoint to check that you can use that as a liveness probe. You are right in the case of leaving the bug unaddressed.

Selling point to keeping the Liveness probe is that it will auto-restart container POD if it's failing while the readiness probe just changes the status from **0/1** to handle the traffic.

if you don't specify the liveness probe it will just decide the container status based on the **PID**.

If you are using the **bash/sh**, **dumb-init** in your docker you might not want **PID 1** to trace instead you want child process **PID 2** to track in that liveness probe would be required.

Comment: "Selling point to keeping the Liveness probe is that it will auto-restart container" --- it's the opposite of "selling": nobody really randomly restarts things hoping it will fix anything.

Comment: "If the service depends on DB or any other service" --- it's the other way around: neither liveness, nor readiness probe should depend on external services (otherwise - if something is unavailable you don't have a chance to handle it gracefully and instead will see all the pods chaotically be unready/being restarted).

Comment: Thanks! I have troubles answering this question: Did we historically had the need of an auto-restart feature in production in the pre k8s/liveness probe era? As I feel that the approach was: detect the deadlock, temporarily workaround it with something like an auto-restart, fix the bug, deploy patch, revert auto-restart. If i'm wrong, an example would help me clear my thoughts. And if we did, then did a default enabled auto-restart do more good (in terms of availability and QoS) than harm in the field?

Comment: Yes, you are right Zerkms absolutely on the liveness, readiness does not depend on the external service however i have come across many ppl that write functions or use probes to check dependencies across external services. definitely, it should be independent to service.